# SQL runs forever

Tags: mysql

I am developing on a local Mysql database.  Yesterday, I ran a query comparing the name fields in two tables and writing out a new record in a new table containing all of the data from both tables on a match.  The process ran for many hours (as indicated by the revolving circle.  When completed, the message said the execution time was 44 minutes. The table contained 2.5 M and 2,800 records.

Now I am copying the 2.5 M table to a new table (so that I then delete the old instance and copy from the new table back to a table with the old name after I first delete the old table.  I am trying this because when I try to add a new column, after 20 to 30 minutes, the SQL editor SQLlog 64 bit editor stops responding.)

I have ran analyze on the table to try to fix any problems that might exist.  Results say everything is ok.

The first copy has been going on for several hours.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you do the copy ?

Comment: Can you post your query, maybe there's something you can fix in order for the query to work more efficiently.

Comment: START TRANSACTIONS:  INSERT employerhold SELECT * FROM employer; COMMIT;  It is running right now.  In checking the ibs files for the two tables I see that they are the same size.  The circle is still spinning.  Is it building the indexes or are they build as the data is being imported?

Comment: The problem is with SQLyog.  I just ran it in Workbench and everything worked fine.